# FlatMapLatest skip trigger until latest observable completes

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm trying to make code that will perform some kind of failable long-running request on particular user action, but ignore sad action while request is active. The goal is allow tapping on button as long as there is no successful emission from request. All errors are skipped. So far I came to code like this, but can't figure out what to do next:

```
struct ErrorError: Error {}
var emitSuccess: Bool = false

// should be something like button.rx.tap
let buttonTap = PublishSubject<Void>()

let requestDuration: RxTimeInterval = 5
let tapInterval: RxTimeInterval = 3


let requestTrigger = buttonTap
    // ???
    .flatMapLatest { (_) -> Observable<Bool> in
        // imitation of http request/parsing etc.
        if emitSuccess {
            return Observable.just(true)
                .delay(requestDuration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .debug("response success", trimOutput: false)
        } else {
            emitSuccess = true
            return Observable.error(ErrorError())
                .materialize()
                .delay(requestDuration, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .dematerialize()
                .debug("response failure", trimOutput: false)
                .catchErrorJustComplete()
        }
    }
    .take(1) //supposed to dispose observation of taps
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)

let requestResponse = requestTrigger
    .debug("response", trimOutput: false)
    .subscribe()

// imitate button tap
Observable<Int>.interval(tapInterval, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .takeUntil(Observable.just(true).delay(20, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance))
    .debug("button tap imitation", trimOutput: false)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
        buttonTap.onNext(())
        return
    })
```

In its current form every tap disposes uncompleted observable and starts a new one, which is undesirable. "???" is the place where I believe should be some clever throttling/skipping operator.

Things which comes to mind:

- replace "???" with `takeUntil(requestResponse)` which will lead to kind of weird recursive subscription (it is even allowed/good/bad practice?)
- use `concatMap` instead of `flatMapLatest` but it kind of queues taps and in this case if some error occurs (no internet connection for example) it probably would occur for all queued taps->requests, meaning I need to *skip* taps
- create my own Observable (using `create`, `deferred` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To may shame as it turned out an answer to this question was on the surface - I should've just used `flatMapFirst`. As I see it many rx operators have unobvious meanings and use cases and the best way to get used to them is practice and reading.

BTW [this nice post](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c) though kind of repeating documentation still rephrases it slightly better for me and was exactly what I read 10 minutes later after I wrote this question (facepalm) (though I could've just read documentation of *all operators* and eventually find one I needed).

Comment: `flatMapFirst` is a beaut. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander Glad my answer helped you. Good luck learning Rx :)